# CURL request check for 3 failed requests before executing command

Tags: bash

I have a service which runs a script to check if an endpoint is returning the status code 200. I want this script to test 3 times before restarting the service.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

status_code=$(curl -X HEAD --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null https://myapi.com/endpoint)

if [[ "$status_code" -ne 200 ]] ; then
  systemctl restart myService
else
  exit 0
fi
```

How do you attempt 3 separate requests checking for status code 200 before restarting the service? How can I have a small 1 second delay between requests?

Comment: `tries=0; while [ "$tries" -lt 3 ]; do status_code=$(curl -X HEAD --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null https://myapi.com/endpoint); [ "$status_code" -eq 200 ] && break; ((tries++)); done; [ "$tries" -eq 3 ] && systemctl restart myService` Compatible with bash and all POSIX shells. Add a `sleep` if desired before the `done` to add delay between `curl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new number variable and initialize it to `0`. Then in your periodic check function, increment the variable's value each time the check does not return `200`. If it returns `200` you reset the check variable to `0`.

If the check variable has a value higher than `3`, you call a function that itself calls `systemctl`. I do not recommend using the `systemctl` utility directly because it will hinder debugging or enhancements (f.e. sending an email on each restart).

Obviously, the check function should be paused while restarting, if the restart isn't on a different thread or a background task, otherwise you're safe as the script will wait for the return of the execution. So time how long it takes to restart and add a buffer to it (maybe one or two extra seconds just to be safe). To repeat the check you can either use cron (let's say, checking every 10 minutes) or wrap the check in a while loop (but be careful with this as you can loop the script endlessly if not done properly).

To pause between checks you can use `sleep x` where `x` is the interval in seconds of pausing, i.e. `sleep 10` will pause for 10 seconds.

I recommend that the bash script is split and organized in dedicated functions, as previously described (one to restart, one to check, if you want to send an e-mail, that would also be a dedicated function and so on). I also recommend that all your reference values are not hardcoded, but rather variables declared at the beginning for easier configuration (i.e. one for your endpoint, one for the number of small pauses, one for the pause while restarting, one for the maximum number of attempts etc.). Dumping the whole code in one block will be hell to maintain, no matter how simple the script is. Trust me on this.

While this should also be straight-forward, I'll still say it. Name your vars intuitively (`MaxTriesBeforeRestart` not `max`) and your functions properly (i.e. `CheckEndPointStatus()` not `test()` or `check_ip()`). And a best-practice is also to comment everything. You'll thank yourself in 2 years when you review the script.

N.B.: if you need this for work, make sure to have the latest curl libs as there were some security vulnerabilities discovered between versions 7.69.0 to 8.3.0 (inclusive).

**EDIT**

User David C. Rankin also posted an example to get you started, it's a basic rundown of what I mentioned before but should be enough for you to get you on track. Thanks for that David :)

```bash
tries=0; 

while (( ++tries <= 3 )); 
do status_code=$(curl -X HEAD --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null https://myapi.com/endpoint); 
(( status_code == 200 )) && break; 
# sleep 1;
done; 

(( tries >= 3 )) && systemctl restart myService
```

David's note: *Compatible with bash and all POSIX shells. Add a sleep if desired before the done to add delay between curl*

My note: I added the sleep with a comment (the `#` symbol). Just remove the `#` to make use of the pause. His example includes the loop approach I mentioned earlier so you can see how to do it properly without ending up in an infinite loop.

You can use his example or expand it with configurable vars or (more) funcs if desired, as I suggested, and if you'll want, you can add other stuff to it (like the mail notification example I mentioned).

Comment: Added the separate thread exception to the rule you mentioned and your starter code that should cover most of what he wants + credited you :) Thanks! If you want to edit or add more, feel free to post in my answer, if you won't start a separate one. And yes, that's why I kept it to a workflow level as well, as I was curious if there is anything else he needs.

Comment: We'll just call that good.

Comment: Is this answer from ChatGPT? It's very "wordy".

Comment: Use arithmetic syntax for arithmetic comparisons, e.g. `(( ++tries <= 3 ))` instead of `[ "$tries" -lt 3 ]` and then later `((tries++))`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, updated David's example with operators. What do you mean "it's wordy"? Did you want me to give him a "here, copy-paste this in your sh" answer? He asked how to approach this and I told him. It's a simple enough task and he already had the basics started, David was kind enough to add a "starter-kit" around my suggestions. I told him the approach you'd take in any programming language for a similar task. So far, my "best xp" with newbies was to give more details and they could ignore what was not relevant instead of two-phrase answers. It's how I wish I was taught to be honest.

Comment: By "wordy" I mean there's a LOT of background information there stating basic and/or obvious things which, if that was given in the answers to every such question, would make the site practically unusable as you wouldn't be able to see the answers to the questions among all the background information. Things like "split your code into functions", "use variables to hold values' and "get the latest version of tools to include security patches". We shouldn't try to teach all fundamentals in every answer so it's easy to see the answers. This looks very much like the answers I see from ChatGPT.

Comment: Hmmm, can't say I agree, but I get why you say it would be a problem. I did take advantage of the fact there were no other answers here (and didn't expect more than 2 others tbh). I'll use links more next time, to keep it more to the point. Thanks for the advice. Updated the HTTP status check too. Missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to do 3 tries adding a 1 second delay in each iteration. Here's an example of a fix to your script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

max_attempts=3
endpoint="https://myapi.com/endpoint"

for ((i=1; i<=$max_attempts; i++)); do
   status_code=$(curl -X HEAD --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null "$endpoint")

   if [[ "$status_code" -eq 200 ]]; then
     exit 0
   fi

   # Add a 1-second delay between requests
   sleep 1
done

# If all attempts fail, restart the service
systemctl restart myService
```

In this script, the `for` loop will try the request up to 3 times. If status code 200 is successfully received, the script will exit with status 0. Otherwise, there will be a 1 second delay between each attempt. If all attempts fail, the script will replace the service (`systemctl restart myService`).